# Select interval of rows including some row with where and order clauses

Tags: sql, postgresql, h2

I have a table foos (id,fieldA,fieldB,fieldC...). And I have an sql query which returns me some set of rows

```
SELECT * from foos WHERE whereClauseN ORDER BY orderClauseM
```

Now, from this set I need to select 5 rows with id X:

1. If the row with id X is in the first 5 rows of the set,then first 5 rows of the set must be returned.
2. if the row with id X is in the last 5 rows of the set, then last 5 rows of the set must be returned.
3. if the row with id X is not in the first 5 and not in the last 5 rows then row with id X and 2 rows before row X and 2 rows after row X must be returned.

How to make such sql query (I need for H2 and PostgreSql)?

For example if I have the following set (for simplicity only fieldA is shown) after executed the above sql code:

```
| id | fieldA |
_______________
| 5  | aaaaa  |
| 7  | bbbbb  |
| 23 | tttttt |
| 22 | ssssss |
| 12 | rrrrrr |
| 96 | eeeeee |
| 48 | qqqqqq |
| 3  | wwwwww |
_______________
```

the for case 1 with X = 7 the following set must be returned:

```
| id | fieldA |
_______________
| 5  | aaaaa  |
| 7  | bbbbb  |
| 23 | tttttt |
| 22 | ssssss |
| 12 | rrrrrr |
_______________
```

the for case 2 with X = 96 the following set must be returned:

```
| id | fieldA |
_______________
| 22 | ssssss |
| 12 | rrrrrr |
| 96 | eeeeee |
| 48 | qqqqqq |
| 3  | wwwwww |
_______________
```

the for case 3 with X = 12 the following set must be returned:

```
| id | fieldA |
_______________
| 23 | tttttt |
| 22 | ssssss |
| 12 | rrrrrr |
| 96 | eeeeee |
| 48 | qqqqqq |
_______________
```

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff I edited the question

Comment: **[edit]** your question and add some sample data and the expected output based on that data. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: What determines first and last?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I edited

Comment: What is the order here?

Comment: @GurV It is a general question with whereClauseM and orderClauseM.

Comment: You do realize that a database table is an unordered set, right?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming one row has id X, then I would be inclined to use window functions to enumerate the rows and get the row number for the "X" value:

```
with t as (
      select f.*,
             row_number() over (orderClauseM) as seqnum,
             count(*) over () as numrows
      from foo t
      where . . .
      order by orderClauseM
     )
select . . .
from (select t.*,
             max(case when id = X then seqnum end) over () as seqnum_X
      from t
     ) t
where (seqnum_X <= 5 and seqnum <= 5) or
      (seqnum_X >= cnt - 5 and seqnum >= cnt - 5) or
      seqnum between seqnum_X - 2 and seqnum_X + 2;
```

Comment: What is `cnt` ?

Comment: And if it is not difficult for you, please explain this line `max(case when id = X then seqnum end) over () as seqnum_X`

Comment: @PavelKasotov . . . `cnt` is the total number of rows in the table (the max of `seqnum`).  The `max()` expression just "spreads" the `seqnum` value for `X` over all the rows.